template specialization in C++ using enable_if
How template specialization works in this case in C++20:
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename E> void AFuncToTest() 
{
    std::cout << "it fails!" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int8_t> || std::is_same_v<T, int16_t>>> void AFuncToTest()
{
    std::cout << "int value!" << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    AFuncToTest<int, int8_t>();
}

OUTPUT: "it fails!"
Why the code is printing it fails! since I defined int8_t e.g.??
The
AFuncToTest<int, int8_t>(); doesnt match:
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int8_t> || std::is_same_v<T, int16_t>>> void AFuncToTest()
If I change the way the algorithm is done it also doesnt work like this:
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename E> void AFuncToTest() 
{
    std::cout << "it fails!" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, int8_t> void AFuncToTest()
{
    std::cout << "int value!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    AFuncToTest<int, int8_t>();
}

OUTPUT: "it fails!"
So I think I'm missing some concept of the templates that is not matching the right result

This doesn't have anything to do with c++20 ... think about what will enable_if_t<> evaluate to.

The type of std::enable_if_t<true || false> is not int8_t.

Because you have two different function templates. AFuncToTest<int, int8_t>() does not match the second overloaded template.

In the second example, you have a non-type template parameter. Meaning it expects a value of type int8_t, not the type itself (if you want to match the second overload)

You are trying to do partial template specialisation but you ended up doing a non type template parameter .... since c++20 is in question look into concepts, otherwise you will want to look up partial template specialisation

In C++20, you might use overload with constraint Demo

It looks like you are trying to activate function AFuncToTest when its template argument T is either int8_t or int16_t. I say this, because the condition you supply tests only parameter T. It does not test parameter E.
// from the OP:
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int8_t> || std::is_same_v<T, int16_t>>

If that is true, then you do not need template parameter E. Parameter T, alone, is sufficient. Parameter E was apparently intended to capture the result of "enable_if_t", but it is not needed.
The following example uses function overloading, rather than function template specialization. The enable_if_t parameters it contains allow you to "turn on" or "turn off" the competing overloads.
When the condition in an enable_if_t parameter evaluates to false, enable_if_t becomes malformed, and the overload using it will not compile. Due to SFINAE, however, the failure is ignored (and does not trigger a compilation error), while the overload is discarded. See CppReference.
// main.cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// This is a "variable template."
template< typename T >
inline constexpr bool is_int8_or_int16 
    = std::is_same_v<T, std::int8_t> || std::is_same_v<T, std::int16_t>;

// Note the "logical not" operator (i.e., the exclamation point).
template< typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_int8_or_int16<T>, bool> = true >
void AFuncToTest()
{
    std::cout << "it fails!" << std::endl;
}

// There is no "logical not" here.
template< typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_int8_or_int16<T>, bool> = true >
void AFuncToTest()
{
    std::cout << "int value!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    AFuncToTest<int>();          // outputs "it fails!"
    AFuncToTest<std::int8_t>();  // outputs "int value!"
}
// end file: main.cpp

Output:
it fails!
int value!

Constraints to the rescue
In a comment below, @Jarod42 points out that the OP is using C++20, and provides the following solution that is valid in C++20 (and later). This solution uses a requires clause, to place a constraint on template parameter T.
// main.cpp 
// Solution by @Jarod42
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> void AFuncToTest()
{
    std::cout << "it fails!" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
    requires (std::is_same_v<T, int8_t> || std::is_same_v<T, int16_t>)
void AFuncToTest()
{
    std::cout << "int value!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    AFuncToTest<int8_t>();
    AFuncToTest<int32_t>();
}
// end file: main.cpp

As above, this works through function overloading.

When the constraint is not satisfied, the function definition where it appears becomes malformed, and drops out of the overload set.
Otherwise, when the constraint is satisfied, the overload set will consist of two functions named AFuncToTest. Since the other criteria for selecting an overload are equal (in the case of function AFuncToTest), the compiler chooses the overload that is "more" constrained.

The notion of "more" constrained has a precise definition which involves the idea of one constraint subsuming another. In most cases, however, all you need is an intuitive understanding to know whether a given overload is "more" constrained than another.

As OP uses C++20, no need of std::enable_if and just use contraint Demo.

You use std::enable_if_t improperly. The section "Notes" on cppreference.com is dedicated to this mistake.
You have two different function templates. AFuncToTest<int, int8_t>() does not match the second overloaded template <typename T, void> void AFuncToTest().
As for the second code snippet in the question, you might want
template <typename T, typename E,
          std::enable_if_t<
              std::is_same_v<E, int8_t> || std::is_same_v<E, int16_t>, int> = 0>
void AFuncToTest() {
  std::cout << "int value!" << std::endl;
}

Now you get error: call to 'AFuncToTest' is ambiguous, because two templates match the template types. The first template should be
template <
    typename T, typename E,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<E, int8_t> && !std::is_same_v<E, int16_t>,
                     int> = 0>
void AFuncToTest() {
  std::cout << "it fails!" << std::endl;
}

The output is int value!

This
template <typename T, int8_t>
void AFuncToTest()

matches
AFuncToTest<int, (int8_t)1>();

and not
AFuncToTest<int, int8_t>();

That is, you promised a value of type int8_t, not a type.
To specialize, you're looking for
template <typename T>
void AFuncToTest<T, int8_t>()

except that won't actually work because you can only partially specialize classes, not functions.  Make a single template function whose body forwards to a templated helper class, partially specialize that helper class, and you're good to go.
See this answer by Alf for a detailed example.
